# Assign numeric values for the alphanumeric cases based on maximum value

Tags: sql, max, sql-server-2019

I have a table as below

| ID | Version | City | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | Sweden | 01 |
| 101 | 1 | Berlin | 20 |
| 101 | 1 | Tokyo | AAB |
| 101 | 1 | Delhi | C23 |
| 101 | 1 | Durban | 34 |
| 101 | 2 | Berlin | 0 |
| 101 | 2 | Vatican | AB |
| 101 | 2 | Mexico | 329 |

Expected output

| ID | Version | City | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | Sweden | 01 |
| 101 | 1 | Berlin | 20 |
| 101 | 1 | Durban | 34 |
| 101 | 1 | Tokyo | 44 |
| 101 | 1 | Delhi | 54 |
| 101 | 2 | Berlin | 0 |
| 101 | 2 | Mexico | 329 |
| 101 | 2 | Vatican | 330 |

Logic
Whenever i find values that are other than numeric [0-9], i have to get maximum value in the specific group(ID,Version) and increment 10 to all the remaining rows. If we see the first group(101,1), I have 2 alphanumeric rows. So i have to take max which is 34 and increment by 10 for each of the remaining rows(44 & 54 - order of the remaining rows doesn't matter).

I have tried below code

```
select ID,Version,
MAX(case when ISNUMERIC(Notes)=1 then Notes+10 end) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Version ORDER BY City)
FROM MYTABLE
```

But this returns the same value(44) for all remaining rows. I have also tried `ROW_NUMBER()..+MAX(Case...)` but that as well not giving the expected outcome.  Please guide me here.

Comment: I think delhi should be 44 and tokyo 54 ! `d < t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can achieve this using the the window functions `MAX()` and `SUM()` :

```
SELECT ID, Version, City,
          CASE WHEN  ISNUMERIC(Notes) = 0 
               THEN ISNULL(max_Notes, 0) + sum(step) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Version ORDER BY City, rn)
               ELSE Notes
          END AS Notes
FROM (
  SELECT *, max(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Notes)=1 THEN Notes END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Version) AS max_Notes,
            CASE WHEN  ISNUMERIC(Notes)=0 THEN 10 END AS step,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Version ORDER BY City) AS rn
  FROM MYTABLE
) as s
ORDER BY ID, Version, Notes;
```

The subquery will get the highest note within each group and assign the sequential step for every alphanumeric value, whereas the outer query will compute the notes for each alphanumeric row based on the max note and the running total on step ordered by City (
If you wish to assign distinct values to duplicate cities within the same group, it's necessary to also order by row number.).

Which is for this dataset :

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
(101,   1,  'Sweden',   '01'),
(101,   1,  'Berlin',   '20'),
(101,   1,  'Tokyo',    'AAB'),
(101,   1,  'Delhi',    'C23'),
(101,   1,  'Durban',   '34'),
(101,   2,  'Berlin',   '0'),
(101,   2,  'Vatican',  'AB'),
(101,   2,  'Mexico',   '329'),
(101,   3,  'New york', 'AC'),
(101,   3,  'Berlin',   'AB'),
(101,   4,  'Paris',    'AC'),
(101,   4,  'Paris',    '25'),
(101,   4,  'Paris',    'AB');
```

Results :

```
ID  Version City    Notes
101 1   Sweden      1
101 1   Berlin      20
101 1   Durban      34
101 1   Delhi       44
101 1   Tokyo       54
101 2   Berlin      0
101 2   Mexico      329
101 2   Vatican     339
101 3   Berlin      10
101 3   New york    20
101 4   Paris       25
101 4   Paris       35
101 4   Paris       45
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kVbKQtrb)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single pass which should be more efficient:

```
select Id, Version, City,
    max(case when ascii(Notes) < 64
             then cast(Notes as int) else 0 end)        ​
       ​over (partition by Id, Version
             ​order by Notes)
  ​+ ​sum(case when ascii(Notes) < 64
             ​​then 0 else 10 end)
       ​​over (partition by Id, Version
             ​​order by Notes) as N
​from T;
```

This drives the logic off of the first character since that appears to be the pattern. `when Note not like '%[A-Za-z]%` would work similarly if that's not true.